# Do non-Catholics ever have the priest visit the sick parishioners and deliver them communion?

Tags: communion, church-local, pastoral-care

Do non-Catholics ever have the priest visit sick parishioners and deliver them communion?

I don't know, but I think it's pretty cool that Catholics have this sort of pastoral care built into their system, and I am wondering whether or not non-Catholics do a similar sort of thing where the priest/pastor/minister would visit the sick parishioners or congregants and give them communion because the sick individuals could not come to Mass but would nevertheless like to receive the Eucharist. What other denominations do this?

Comment: most denominations do not refer to their leaders as "priest" - most call them "elder", "pastor", "overseer", "brother", or perhaps "bishop"

Answer (score 2):

The Church of England does this.

It's an important part of the clergy's ministry to their little bit of the country — and they will go to anyone resident in the parish who would receive communion in the Church of England but can't (so it's not restricted to actual members of the Church of England).

Although the Church of England is the established Church in England, and each incumbent has a statutory role within his parish, it's highly likely that any Anglican minister would operate in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

It is common in the Christian Churches, Churches of Christ, and Disciples of Christ. These are part of the Stone-Campbell Restoration Movement.

Comment: Is there a reason?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. I would add that The Episcopal Church encourages a [Lay Eucharistic Ministry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eucharistic_Minister) by which parishioners are charged with administration of the sacrament to the homebound.

Comment: Is there a reason?

Comment: The Episcopal Church believes participation in Holy Eucharist the predominant act of Christian worship. Therefore every effort is made in reaching out to all baptized Christians who wish to take part, whether they can make it to the building or not.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's a congregation-by-congregation thing. At one time I attended a church in the [URCNA](http://www.urcna.org/) denomination that followed this practice for many years; at some point a new pastor convinced the elders to cease the practice on the grounds of lack of Biblical support.

Answer (score 0):

Priesthood of the LDS church certainly take the Sacrament to the sick and the elderly. In some cases they will attend nursing homes and hospitals and hold a service if the numbers warrant it.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This doesn't really have much to do with your answer, but I find that sharing the following tends to help new visitors avoid mistaking the purpose of this site. I do hope to see more from you!  When you get a chance, please see [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)